# Android Studio has wrong file path for custom class

Tags: android-studio

My app has several custom classes which are held in a folder called 'models', and accessed via 'com.myname.appname.models.classname'. It was working fine until recently, but suddenly it's crashing out when it tries to inflate the layout that uses one of these classes.

The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.myname.appname.ColourCell
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.myname.appname.ColourCell
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.myname.appname.ColourCell" on path: DexPathList[...]
```

So it's looking for `com.myname.appname.ColourCell` instead of `com.myname.appname.models.ColourCell`.

I've Googled the ClassNotFoundException error, and found the following solutions, none of which seem to work:

- Enable MultiDex
- Update compileSDKVersion
- Add 'maven' support
- Disabling Instant Run

It still crashes out with the same error when it tries to inflate the layout.

I have no idea what to try next. I don't understand gradle at all - I've always just used it! The solutions I found online seemed to centre around the gradle files, though, so I've included them below:

app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'xxx'
            keyPassword 'xxx'
            storeFile file('xxx')
            storePassword 'xxx'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myname.appname"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.0.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        freeConfig {
            applicationId 'com.myname.appname.free'
        }
        paidConfig {
            applicationId 'com.myname.appname.full'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {

        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

app-name:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I've tried cleaning the project and rebuilding, with no success. It's running fine until it reaches that particular inflate statement and tries to use the class that it can't find.  I've absolutely no idea what to try next.

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a brainwave and moved (via the 'refactor' menu option) the 'ColourCell' class to the path that AS was looking in.  That worked. I was then able to move it back (again via 'refactor') to 'models', and it's still working.

Comment: Since this was your answer, you are welcome (but not required) to accept it, by clicking the tick/check mark. Self-answers are most welcome here!